# Error Loading tiny_tds in CentOS 7

Tags: ruby

I'm trying to use the tiny_tds to connect to a MS SQL with Dashing widget.  I run into below error when trying to start my job.

> /root/.rbenv/versions/2.4.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/gems/thin-1.6.4/lib/thin/server.rb:107:
>   warning: constant ::Fixnum is deprecated bundler: failed to load
>   command: thin (/root/.rbenv/versions/2.4.1/bin/thin) LoadError: cannot
>   load such file -- tiny_tds

The gem is already installed.

> [root@localhost todo]#  gem list | grep tiny_tds tiny_tds (2.0.0)
>
> [root@localhost todo]# tsql -C [TinyTds][v2.0.0][tsql]: /usr/bin/tsql
>   Compile-time settings (established with the "configure" script)
>                               Version: freetds v0.95.81
>                freetds.conf directory: /etc
>        MS db-lib source compatibility: yes
>           Sybase binary compatibility: yes
>                         Thread safety: yes
>                         iconv library: yes
>                           TDS version: 4.2
>                                 iODBC: no
>                              unixodbc: yes
>                 SSPI "trusted" logins: no
>                              Kerberos: yes
>                               OpenSSL: no
>                                GnuTLS: yes
>
> [root@localhost todo]# yum list freetds* Loaded plugins:
>   fastestmirror, langpacks Loading mirror speeds from cached hostfile  *
>   base: ftp.iitm.ac.in  * epel: epel.mirror.angkasa.id  * extras:
>   ftp.iitm.ac.in  * updates: ftp.iitm.ac.in Installed Packages
>   freetds.x86_64
>   0.95.81-1.el7                                              @epel freetds-devel.x86_64
>   0.95.81-1.el7                                              @epel Available Packages freetds-doc.noarch
>   0.95.81-1.el7                                              epel [root@localhost todo]#

I don't have much experience working with Ruby so please let me know if you need further information.

Comment: Can you indicate the command you're running?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like your job is running with bundler, which means it will look in Gemfile.lock to find the version. Even if it's installed on your OS, it won't work if it's not in the Gemfile.

Therefore, ensure it's specified in the Gemfile, run `bundle`, and try again.

Comment: The issue was due to not adding 'tiny_tds' to the Gemfile ( I have added it to Gemfile.lock by mistake). Adding the gem and running 'bundle install' resolved the issue.


Thanks!